# Find the longest sequence of the same value in vector, R

Tags: r, vector, repeat

Does anyone have an idea of how to determine the longest repetition of any value in a vector?

So for example I have the following vector:

```
sample <- c(1,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,4,3,2)
```

The expected output should be `4` times (as there are four consecutive 6 in the vector). So I am interested in finding out the length of maximal repetition of one same value.

Comment: You can do `max(rle(sample)$lengths)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle`

```
with(rle(sample), max(lengths))
#[1] 4
```

If we need it for each unique value,

```
with(rle(sample), tapply(lengths, values, FUN = max))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
#3 1 1 1 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

with `rle()`

```
max(rle(sample)$lengths)
```